# What is /com/host?

Tags: operating-systems

The Perl documentation for [`Sys::Hostname`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Sys/Hostname.html) contains:

> Attempts several methods of getting the system hostname *[...]*. It tries the first available of *[blah blah]* , and the file `/com/host`. If all that fails it croaks.

What systems is this `/com/host` used on? It's a very ungooglable filename, and this is the first time I have heard of it.

Comment: The only mention of `/com` I have found is in Apollo Domain/OS, where it is listed as "AEGIS Shell commands", but still no `/com/host`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to look at the actual code for Sys::Hostname you would see this:

```
# method 6 - Apollo pre-SR10
|| eval {
    local $SIG{__DIE__};
    my($a,$b,$c,$d);
    ($host,$a,$b,$c,$d)=split(/[:\. ]/,`/com/host`,6);
}
```

so obviously it is on Apollo, pre SR10.

I have no idea what that means - it could be on the moon for all I know ;)  Did they use Perl for the moon landings?  So pre-SR10 could be before Saturn-V Rocket 10?

Comment: That would be Apollo [Domain/OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/OS), a networked and somewhat Unix-like operating system for Apollo workstations. SR10 is the version number. (Facepalm queued for forgetting to check the source.)

Comment: @grawity you should swing by root-access chat - we're having a facepalm fest today.

Comment: After some more research, it appears that "pre-SR10" means Apollo AEGIS, not Domain/OS (which started at SR10).

Comment: I still say it's something to do with the moon landings.